# Unable to use unix shell commands in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, unix, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter notebook and python using Anaconda. However, I have a problem when I try running any UNIX shell commands like 'cat' for example. I get the following error

```
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried re-installing Git and Anaconda but I still face the same issue. I am using Windows 10 by the way.

Comment: Is `cat` available on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 commandline does not have a `cat` command.

You can either use the Windows 10 equivalent, ie `type`, or install a package like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which provides Unix-equivalent commands.

Comment: Finally got it working. I thought installing Git did the job but it seems it did not but Cygwin did it for me.

Comment: how do I install it for linux?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in git and Anaconda and it doesn't have to do anything with your operating version. Jupyter does not recognise all the UNIX commands instead you can use their windows equivalent and that will solve the problem.
For example: In place of `ls` you can use its windows equivalent i.e. `dir`
             which will give you the same result.

Hope this may help you!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command

*!type*

in place of

*!cat*

in Windows 10 Jupyter Notebook and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Install git bash in windows, it allows you to run most of the Linux commands.
Start Jupyter notebook from Git bash instead command prompt and it accepts Unix commands!